# Graph Theory: connected graph and spanning tree

Tags: graph-theory

Firstly, I would like to understand more about "spanning tree". I have read some definition, but still, cant 100% understand. It would be better if there is a graph to illustrate.

Secondly, comes to the main question. Why is the number of edges of the spanning tree (T) = V-1? (V: vertices) Some references use this as a fact but I can't find why.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find graphs to illustrate the concept of a spanning tree on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).

That a spanning tree has $V-1$ edges can be proved by induction: For the base case, a spanning tree for $1$ vertex has $0$ edges. For the induction step, delete any edge. This cuts the spanning tree into two spanning trees for two vertex subsets with, say, $V_1$ and $V_2$ vertices, with $V_1+V_2=V$. By the induction hypothesis, these have $V_1-1$ and $V_2-1$ edges, respectively. Including the deleted edge, this yields a total of $(V_1-1)+(V_2-1)+1=V_1+V_2-1=V-1$ edges in the original spanning tree.

Comment: Can i do it in this way?
base case: 1 V corresponds to 0 E. Base case is correct.
Assume that for $v_k$ vertices, it is true that the spanning tree will have $V_k-1$ edges.
For $V_(k+1)$ vertices' case:
For the first $v_k$ vertices, its spanning tree has $v_k-1$ edges. And since there is one more vertex in the graph, it needs one more edge to connect it.
Therefore, no. of edges is $(v_k-1)+1=v_k$. So, k+1 case is correct. And finish the proof

Comment: @JasonNg: I don't understand your notation. What's $v_k$, and what's $V_k$? Are they meant to be the same? So far, we only had $V$ (in your question) and $V_1$ and $V_2$ (in my answer) -- what does the $k$ index? Are you talking about $k$ different graphs now?

Comment: Proposition: a connected graph $G(V_k,E)$ will have a spanning tree with no. of edges $=V_k-1$.

For base case, where $k=1$. Then no. of edges of the spanning tree is $0$. P(1) is correct.

Assume P(k) is correct for $k$ vertices in $G$.
For $k+1$ vertices in $G$,
no. of edges in spanning tree is calculated as follow:
first $k$ vertices, no. of vertices is $V_k-1$. Since no of vertices in this case is $k+1$, one more edge is need to connect to the extra vertices. Therefore, total no. of edges in this case is $(V_k-1)+1=V_k$
Then, by the induction hypothesis, it is true.

Comment: @JasonNg: I'm still not following your notation. $G(V_k,E)$ usually means that $V_k$ is the vertex set. But in $V_k-1$ you seem to be treating $V_k$ as a number?

Comment: number?!  Then I think I got the wrong understanding....

Comment: Let me study again. Thank you